# CSS: how to make a list item containing a form "submittable"?

Tags: html, css

**Looking for a non-JS solution.** Say I had something like this:

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <form>
         <fieldset>
            ...
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
         </fieldset>
      </form>
   </li>
   ...
</ul>
```

Is there a way to do the following **without JS**:

1. Make the submit button invisible, and
2. Make any part of the `<li>` clickable (meaning, it will submit the form)

???

Comment: Without javascript? I'm thinking no...

Comment: Can't the "hot spot" of the submit button be defined to encompass the area the `<li>` is using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JS to submit a form without a sumbit button:

```
<li onClick="document.forms["myform"].submit();">my LI</li>
<form id="myform">
<!-- FORM -->
</form>
```

This is just a quick way to achieve this. If you are using JS for other problems as well you should not implement it directly (inline).

UPDATED - without JS:

Without JS you definitely need the input, but you could style it with css to your needs:

```
input.submit { border:none; background-color:transparent; display:block; width:200px;
height:200px; position:absolute; }
```

Via `top` and `left` you could place it over the li. `position:relative` might be better . it depends how you want to position it.

```
<input class="submit" type="submit" />
```

Comment: Looking for a non-JS solution.

Comment: Look above. You might achieve it via css